# Symfony - Form - IntegerType accepting 1.00 (x.00) Values as valid

Tags: symfony

I have below form builder attribute,

```
$builder->add('Adjustment', IntegerType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Amount',
                'data' => (int)$this->statusAdjustment["adjustment"],
                'required'  => true,
                'rsounding_mode' => \NumberFormatter::ROUND_HALFDOWN,
            ));
```

When i enter 1.00 as the value it accept the value and form get submitted in the front because the in the HTML it sets as input type="number",

```
<input type="number" id="Adjustment" name="adjustment[Adjustment]" required="required" value="">
```

however, I want to set it not to accept 1.00 or round the 1.00 to 1, because otherwise form gets invalid when submitted a value like 1.00 but 1 is good,

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

}
```

Any idea on how to overcome this issue ? Because form gets valid only if you submit "1" or integer values, however in the frontend it accept "1.00" as an integer type.

Comment: i was managed to pass them but that didnt fix the original issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a event listner to the form in the pre-submit event.

```
 ->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            if (!$data) {
                return;
            }
            $data['Adjustment'] = (int)$data['Adjustment'];
            $event->setData($data);
        }
    );
```